# Comparing a DateTime object to a DateInterval and subtracting DateInterval from DateTime under certain conditions

Tags: php, datetime, time

im creating a function that checks the difference between two times, if the difference is greater than 1hour I would like the fucntion to subtract to an hour from the difference! This is the code I have so far;

```
$LHA = $row['LHA'];
$AAS = $row['AAS'];

$f = calculate_difference($LHA, $AAS);

function calculate_difference($a, $b){
  $e = new DateInterval('PT1H');
  $e->format('%H');
  $datetime1 = new DateTime($a);
  $datetime2 = new DateTime($b);
  $interval = $datetime1->diff($datetime2);

  if ($interval <= $e) { 
    $interval = new DateTime('00:00:00');
    return $interval;
  } else if ($interval > $e) {
    $interval->sub(new DateInterval('PT1H'));
    return $interval;
  }
}
```

Comment: Can you show some example data for `$LHA` and `$AAS`, and show what is the expected output.

Comment: $LHA = 2:0
$AAs = 1:30 the data is fetched from a mysql database from a "Time" field!

Comment: MySQL TIME filed is in format `xx:xx:xx`, not `x:xx`! **What is the expected output?**

Comment: The expected out put is if a (LHA) > b (AAS) by 1 hour subtract 1 hour from total difference!

Comment: So if `$LHA = '07:00:00'` and `$AAS = '02:00:00'`, then the output should be `04:00:00`?

Comment: The difference between thoose two examples isnt 5 hours, its 7 hours then because 7hours > 1hours 7hours - 1hours = 6hours

Comment: Under what logic can difference between 7hours and 2hours be 7hours? You lost me...

Comment: Its a time in the day not a messurement in hours! or am i using the mysql time field wrong ?

Comment: It doesn't matter, difference in both cases is 5hours. And DateTime::diff() will return 5hours.

Comment: AAS will never be erliar than LHA though, so it will be 14:00 stored in the database

Comment: Again, how can it be stored as `14:00` in database where field type is `TIME` ??

Comment: It just works I insert the users selected "time" into the TIME (LHA,AAS) fields and it just displays the time?